# What is the sutta in which the Buddha described focusing the mind as similar to whittling?

Tags: pali-canon, sutras

I believe there is a sutta in which the Buddha uses an example of whittling or carving a piece of wood to describe the process of refocusing your mind in meditation. What is this sutta?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that these are what you asking for.

- Maha-Malunkya Sutta: Insight Meditation To Be Anāgāmi-Ariya

http://tipitaka.wikia.com/wiki/Maha-Malunkya_Sutta

- Maha Saropama Sutta: The Longer Heartwood-simile Discourse

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.029.than.html

- Angulimala Sutta: About Angulimala

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.086.than.html

Comment: Please also quote the relevant fragment (sentence or paragraph) from the sutta.

Answer (score 1):

My person does not reminde on a sutta taking the whittling of wood as a sample (for now), but a good simile of Ajahn Chah, which transports the message that if one does not make the basics, like generosity, virtue, the 7 treasures complete, it does not make much sense to meditate. Like:

> **[Making Tables & Chairs](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/chah/insimpleterms_en.html)**
>
> It's good to make the mind pure and at peace, but it's hard. You have to start with the externals — your bodily actions and words — and work your way in. The path that leads to purity, to being a contemplative, is a path that can wash away greed, anger, and delusion. You have to exercise restraint and self-control, which is why it's hard — but so what if it's hard?
>
> It's like taking wood to make a table or make a chair. It's hard, but so what if it's hard? The wood has to go through that process. Before it can become a table or a chair, we have to go through the coarse and heavy stages.
>
> It's the same with us. We have to become skillful where we aren't yet skillful, admirable where we aren't yet admirable, competent where we aren't yet competent.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gain by means of trade and exchange]*